# Inicio de sesión con privilegios PHP

Tags: php, html, login

Realizo un login en el cual necesito que sea por privilegios es decir; si el el campo **username=admin** me deje acceder al sistema de lo contrario me niegue dicho acceso, realice el login pero me marca error en contraseña o correo electrónico  en la sentencia que esta en el archivo login.php coloque la variable $username="admin" y justamente ahí no me deja acceder al sistema y si lo quito sin problema entro.

Justamente es en esta linea.

```
 $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["email"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["password"],ENT_QUOTES)));


$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='$email' AND password = '$password'");
$username = "admin";

    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query,$username)) {


            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
            header("location: ../dashboard.php");
```

Gracias de antemano / Saludos.

[image: Tabla user]

**Estructura tabla de datos user**

```
id                 Primaria  int(15)
username                     varchar(50)
name                         varchar(50)
email                        varchar(50)
password                     varchar(50)
profile_pic                  varchar(50)
is_active                    tinyint(4)
kind                         int(15)
created_at
```

**Login.php**

```html
   <?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token']!=='') {
  
//Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
include "../config/config.php";

$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["email"],ENT_QUOTES)));
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["password"],ENT_QUOTES)));

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='$email' AND password = '$password'");

 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
  

   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
   header("location: ../dashboard.php");
   

 }else{
  $invalid=sha1(md5("contrasena y email invalido"));
  header("location: ../index.php?invalid=$invalid");
 }
}else{
 header("location: ../");
}

?>
```

**Index.php**

```html
<?php
    session_start();
    include "config/config.php";
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])&& $_SESSION['user_id']==null) {
        header("location: index.php");
    }
?>
<?php 
    $id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from user where id=$id");
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $username = $row['username'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $profile_pic = $row['profile_pic'];
        $created_at = $row['created_at'];
  
    }


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
     <link rel="icon" href="images/cropped-favicon-192x192.png" sizes="192x192" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title><?php echo $title." ".$name; ?> </title>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Font Awesome -->
        <link href="css/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- NProgress -->
        <link href="css/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <!-- iCheck -->
       <link href="css/iCheck/skins/flat/green.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <!-- Datatables -->
        <link href="css/datatables.net-bs/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/datatables.net-buttons-bs/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/datatables.net-fixedheader-bs/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/datatables.net-responsive-bs/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/datatables.net-scroller-bs/css/scroller.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- jQuery custom content scroller -->
        <link href="css/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <!-- bootstrap-daterangepicker -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
        <link href="css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- MICSS button[type="file"] -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/micss.css">

    </head>

    <body class="nav-md">
        <div class="container body">
            <div class="main_container">
                <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
                    <div class="left_col scroll-view">
                        <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
                          <a href="#" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i> <span>Incidentes</span></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                            <!-- menu profile quick info -->
                                <div class="profile clearfix">
                                    <center>
                                    <div class="profile_info">
                                        <span>Bienvenido,</span>
                                        <h2><?php echo $name;?></h2>
                                    </div>
         </center>
                                </div>
                            <!-- /menu profile quick info -->

                        <br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola el error lo tienes en que tu variable `$username` que es una variable que estas declarando mas no una variable que esta recuperando desde la base de datos `$username = "admin";` sugiero cambiar un poco la logica:

```
//Ejecuta un Resultado con la conexion y tu query
$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//Hace un associativo de los resultados obtenidos
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
// en este caso $row['name'] == 'NOMBRE' , $row['password'] == 'PASSWORD', ETC ETC

if ($row['username'] == 'Admin') {

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
            header("location: ../dashboard.php");
}
else {
Lo que ocurrirá si no es `admin`
}
```

**Codigo login (modificado)**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['token']) && $_POST['token']!=='') {

    //Contiene las variables de configuracion para conectar a la base de datos
    include "../config/config.php";

    $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["email"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["password"],ENT_QUOTES)));

//SE DECLARA EL QUERY
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='$email' AND password = '$password'";

//Ejecuta un Resultado con la conexion y tu query
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $query);
//Hace un associativo de los resultados obtenidos
    $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
// en este caso $row['name'] == 'NOMBRE' , $row['password'] == 'PASSWORD', ETC ETC

if ($row['username'] == 'admin') {

            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];
            header("location: ../dashboard.php");
  }
  else { //cierra el if admin
header("location: ../");
} //cierra el else admin
} // cierra el primer if declarado

?>
```

Comment: Buenas tardes @Jose, implemente el codigo que me hiciste favor de proporcionarme pero me marca dos Warning en estas lineas  Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\action\login.php on line 16

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\tickets\action\login.php on line 18, modifico el código tal cual lo tengo al día de hoy gracias de antemano

Comment: He modificado tu código nuevamente, he comentado casi que cada linea explicando que ocurre en cada paso, trata de leer tu codigo, espero que con la orientación que te he brindado puedas encaminarte a terminar de escribir tu script.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda ya realiza lo que necesitaba el codigo. Saludos

Comment: Tengo una duda se supone que en en el ´else {
header("location: ../"); }' tendria dirigirte a otra pagina si no tiene los accesos correspondientes, pero solo la pantalla se pone en blanco y no lo realiza.

Comment: Le coloque la siguiente linea pero no sale el mensaje ni dijere a otra pagina si no tiene los permisos para acceder  ' else {
 $messages[] = "Lo siento, no cuentas con los permisos necesarios.";
 echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href="index.php";
        </script>';

}'

Comment: sugerencia: si aun no haz terminado de solucionar el problema con PHP no mezclar JavaScript, para mi eso no tiene sentido. he cambiado la posicion de una de las llaves, debes ver que toda function if debe abrir y cerrar llaves y toda function else tambien.. como te indique debes leer tu propio codigo, el mismo debe tener un origen y un final y tratar de ser claro, comentarlo es una de las cosas que ayuda a detectar problemas como el que tienes..!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el aporte, tomare en cuenta tus comentarios. Saludos